# collection of two dimensional arrays in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf

I'm new in C# and i was wondering if it is possible to store two dimensional arrays in a List or Observable Collection like this : `ObservableCollection<double[,]> TwoDarray = new ObservableCollection<double[,]>();`  and access each List element(the arrays in our case) with an index which points to  specific elements(arrays) of the List.For example i want to plot some data from a custom class and i want to make a combobox which you can select and plot previous inputs if the user wants to plot previous inputs.

Comment: Yes. It is possible.

Comment: Yes, also check out `Dictionary<key,value>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the multidimensional array you mentioned in your post

```
double[,]
```

then you can create a list of those objects

 Like:

```
 List<double[,]> TwoDarray = new List<double[,]>();
```

Then to add one to the array you just use the list .add method

```
TwoDarray.add(new double[,]);
```

To access your new array you can simply use your

```
var x = TwoDarray[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
    List<int[,]> myList = new List<int[,]>();

    myList.Add(new int[,] {{1, 2}});
    myList.Add(new int[,] {{3, 4}});
    myList.Add(new int[,] {{5, 6}});

    Console.WriteLine(myList[0][0, 0]); // Output: 1
    Console.WriteLine(myList[2][0, 1]); // Output: 6
```